# Nomenclature confusion regarding carboxylate and ester

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

I suddenly thought about these 2 compounds that seem to have the same name. Aren't both of them methyl propanoate? How do we differentiate them apart name wise?

[image: Methyl Propanoate??]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From context (in spoken word) and/or the presence or absence of a space (in written word). The one on the left is a neutral molecule whereas the one on the right is a charged molecule. In mentioning the given compounds there should be context to indicate a charge. For example, the one on the left is "*methyl propanoate*", whereas the one on the left would be "*2-methylpropanoate*" (also called isobutyrate).  The isobutyrate would usually be described as an ion (e.g. "*sodium methylpropanoate*") which would provide clarity as well.

Now it is possible to see the 2-methylpropanoate written as just "*methylpropanoate*" since there are no isomers to cause ambiguity. In either case, though notice that names for the left molecule have a space between "*methyl*" and "*propanoate*" whereas names for the right molecule do not. That is how you can tell between an ester from an anion.

Answer (score 4):

There is not supposed to be a space between the substituent prefixes (e.g. methyl) and the parent structure (e.g. propanoate), so your second structure is *methylpropanoate*, or more correctly *2-methylpropanoate*.

In the ester there is a space between methyl and propanoate, i.e. *methyl propanoate*.

Comment: Lack of attention to this minor detail is a frequent cause of errors in nomenclature.